# Is there a built-in mock object to pass in to Python unit test?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I commonly instantiate a `Mock` object during unit tests.  I am sick of:

1. Having to type `from unittest.mock import Mock`
2. And then instantiate a `Mock` object via `mock = Mock()`

I am wondering, does `pytest`, `unittest.mock`, `pytest-mock`, etc. have a built in way of passing in a `Mock` object?

Here is what my current workflow looks like:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock


def test_something() -> None:
    mock = Mock()
    mock.func()
    mock.func.assert_called_once()
```

---

**Research**

I know with `pytest-mock`, I can at least get around the import via the [`mocker` fixture](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/#usage).

```py
def test_something(mocker) -> None:
    mock = mocker.Mock()
    mock.func()
    mock.func.assert_called_once()
```

I am hoping to just be able to do something like this:

```py
def test_something(mock) -> None:
    mock.func()
    mock.func.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pytest` just make a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-fixture-api).

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def my_cool_mock():
    mocked = Mock()
    yield mocked

def test_something(my_cool_mock) -> None:
    my_cool_mock.func()
    my_cool_mock.func.assert_called_once()
```

Otherwise, just use `pytest-mock`.

Comment: Yeah, I had also thought of this.  I was hoping for something that didn't require custom fixturing on my end at all.  I was hoping it would just be built-in.